# How to load/write environment specific details from configuration file to webpack generated budle js file?

Tags: import, webpack, ecmascript-6, require, webpack-dev-server

I have a environment specific config.js file that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    local: {
        apiHost: 'http://localhost',
        apiPort: '3003',
    },
    development: {
        apiHost: 'http://192.168.1.49',
        apiPort: '3003',
    },
    testing: {
        apiHost: 'http://192.168.1.50',
        apiPort: '3003',
    }
}
```

To use this this file I write:-

```
const config = require('./config.js')[env];
```

That loads everything of config.js in my webpack (v-1) generated bundle.js file. I want only environment specific details to be written in bundle.js file, don't want to expose all environment details in bundle.js file.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't want to create mutiple environment files.

Answer (score -1):

Make use of Webpack's DefinePlugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

In your webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const envConfig = require('/path/to/config.js');

plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    ENV_CONFIG: envConfig[your_env] 
  });
]
```

In your application

```
if(ENV_CONFIG) {
  console.log('Your environment details:', ENV_CONFIG);
}
```

Comment: I need to a webpack loader or something that will help me to load only environment specific config files. The answer above will not help me.

Comment: Not quite sure what are you trying to achieve. To load the environment specific **properties** (`apiHost` and `apiPort`) or to load a bunch of environment specific config **files**?